# JSON Deserializer Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, jsf

I have this entity; transferRate is persisted as json format in database :

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private String currencyIsoCode;

    private String currencyIsoNum;

    @Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
    private Map<String, Object> transferRate = new HashMap();

  }
```

and in the client project iam using Rest Template to get list of currencies like that

```
   ResponseEntity<List<Currency>> listResponse =
restTemplate.exchange(RestApiConstants.BASE_URL + CurrenciesRestApiConstants.LIST_CURRENCIES,
                    HttpMethod.GET, null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
                    });
    currencyList = listResponse.getBody();
```

But iam getting this error

```
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `double` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

The class in the client side is like that

```
@Data
public class Currency implements Serializable {

    private String currencyIsoCode;

    private String currencyIsoNum;

    private Map<String, Object> transferRate;

 }
```

What iam I doing wrong

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your field is defined as a `Map<String, Object>`, so Jackson tries to deserialize the map value as an `Object`. From JSON point of view, an object is a set of properties in curly braces. This is where the error comes from:

```
Cannot deserialize value of type `double` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
```

Apparently on the client side you send a numeric value, so you need to define `transferRate` with the numeric type, e.g.:

```
@Convert(converter = JpaConverterJson.class)
private Map<String, Double> transferRate = new HashMap();
```

And use a similar type on the client:

```
private Map<String, Double> transferRate;
```